# Excel Not Responding Issue when dragging to auto-fill, saving and copying cells, an unlikely fix was running services.msc in the background

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, in which Excel has a "not responding" problem that occurs when an user tries the drag auto-fill feature and sometimes at random when saving, copy cells etc.
the Office version is 2013.
Tried restarting cryptographicservices, print-spooler services too.Error was still present.
But when i  keep "services.msc" running in the background and then work in excel and try drag auto-fill and other things,  Excel works fine.

Clearly i don’t understand this behavior.
Please help in finding a better solution.

Comment: Try disabling Graphics Hardware Acceleration option in Excel. With an Excel file open, go to Menu File --> Options -- Advanced --> Display --> tick or check the checkbox for Disable hardware graphics acceleration.

Comment: @patkim tried it didnt work

Comment: Also what if you try starting Excel in safe mode? Keep CTRL key pressed while you run Excel  to start it in safe mode. Now how it behaves if you close services.msc?

Comment: @patkim started excel in safe mode and then closed services.msc, the above mentioned not responding problem still exists.

Comment: "services.msc" running in the background, do you mean just opening services.msc and then running excel, it works good?

Comment: I do not have much knowledge of Windows Server 2012. Just a small suggestion that in case restart is an option, you may just try selective or diagnostic startup thru msconfig and also see if there are any non-Microsoft services to temporarily disable under Services Tab and check again.